# Installing shadow-utils via microdnf failing in Docker ubi-minimal image

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm getting error while running my Dockerfile `The command '/bin/sh -c microdnf -y install shadow-utils' returned a non-zero code: 1     Execution failed for task`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker.xxx.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal

ARG DISTRIB_DIRECTORY

LABEL Team="xxx"

COPY  ${DISTRIB_DIRECTORY} /usr/app/


RUN rm -fr /etc/yum.repos.d/* && curl xxx.net/scripts/add-ubi8-repo.sh | sh
RUN microdnf -y install shadow-utils

RUN    microdnf -y install --nodocs java-11-openjdk-headless tzdata-java && microdnf clean all
RUN    groupadd --gid 1001 mygroup
RUN    useradd --uid 1001 --gid mygroup --shell /bin/bash --home-dir /usr/app --no-create-home myuser
RUN    chown -R myuser:mygroup /usr/app
RUN    chmod -R u+rwx /usr/app
USER myuser

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/app/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["xxx.jar"]
```

If I delete `RUN microdnf -y install shadow-utils` I get the same error with the next line.

Any suggestion why I'm getting this error and how to fix this?

Comment: "Returned a non-zero code" pretty much just means "it didn't work".  Can you [edit] the question to include the complete error?  That specific package seems slightly unusual since there aren't usually user passwords in Docker, almost nothing would ever use an `/etc/shadow` file.

Comment: what does `xxx.net/scripts/add-ubi8-repo.sh` do . i ran the install command bellow that without the above line and it was ok

Comment: @AlirezaPourchali, it adds Red Hat Linux  repository

Comment: make sure that the repository you are using (`docker.xxx.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal`) contains the `shadow-utils` package, and if does not contain it, you can try updating the repository or adding a different repository that provides this package,it can be done by modifying the `add-ubi8-repo.sh` script or by adding a new script to add the necessary repository.

Comment: @DavidMaze, unfortunatelly it's a full log

Comment: If I delete `RUN microdnf -y install shadow-utils` I get the same error with the next line.